# Android - osmdroid - ResourceProxy.string

Tags: android, osmdroid

Can someone explain to me how to use this parameter?
If i use a custom online tile source, can I set it null?
In which case this parameter will be used?

```
XYTileSource source = new XYTileSource("custom", ResourceProxy.string.?, getMinZoom(), getMaxZoom(), 256, ".png", new String[]{});
```

According to `https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/wiki/How-to-use-the-osmdroid-library` :

```
mapView.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.MAPNIK);
```

How can I create a custom tile source?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was deleted ages ago. If you are on a verison of osmdroid using the string class,  it's time to update

Comment: I just download the osmdroid-android-5.6.5, how can I create a custom online tile source? By the way, the `ResourceProxy.string` still existes in this version.

Comment: not too sure about that one. It's probably some silly caching issue with gradle or android studio. Source: I deleted it the resource proxy